# El programa en Java no ejecuta y sale error SQLException No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Este programa no me ejecuta ya que me devuelve el error del titulo (y un par más) que al parecer son referentes a la base de datos.

Es un programa que posee un *login* como *main*, este *login* esta conectado a la base de datos. Es necesario conocer sus usuarios para entrar.

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/facial_recognition

Código (clase para la conexión):

```
package util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConectaBanco {

    public Statement stm;
    public ResultSet rs;
    public Connection conn;

    private final String driver = "org.mysql.Driver";
    private final String path = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/facial_recognition";
    private final String user = "root";
    private final String pass = "";

    public void conexao() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("jdbc.Driver", driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(path, user, pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void desconecta() {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void executaSQL(String SQL) {
        try {
            stm = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stm.executeQuery(SQL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes se debe de crear una nueva instancia del `Driver`, lo cual permite la correcta conexión con la Base de Datos, posterior a eso se crea la conexión con `url`, `user`, `pass`

```java
       try{
            //datos para conectarse a la base de datos
            String user = new String("root");
            String pass = new String("");
            //dato de la direccion de la base de datos
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombreDB";
            //Declaracion de instancia del driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); // esto es lo que falta
            //Crear conexion a base de datos
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        }catch (SQLException sqle){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error SQL" + sqle);
        }
```